# Verb 'be' + -ed

Tags: verbs

In the English grammar, the progressive be must follow an -ing verb. I could not find anything to support the verb to be + -ed. For example, "You better be prepared for tomorrow."

Comment: It can be either "passive voice" or simply, as here, "prepared" is used as an adjective, as in "I am prepared".

Comment: Looks like imperative to me, actually. Or a *should* was casually omitted. Here *prepared* is just the participle used a adjective/adverb.

Comment: In order to be an imperative, it should be something like **be prepared for tomorrow**.

Comment: I think it's a mistake. It should be "You had better be prepared for tomorrow", often contracted to "You'd better be prepared for tomorrow" whence the fact that you will see the verb omitted sometimes. See: http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/hadbetter/menu.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you are parsing the sentence slightly incorrectly.  I would break it down like this:

*You better* (you better what?)
*be* (be what?)
*prepared*

Let's examine it in more detail.
**You better** is essentially a *modal* meaning **you should**.  In English, we follow a modal with a *bare infinitive*.  The bare infinitive of *to be* is just *be*.  So this is a statement about what you should be.  *Prepared* is a **participle**, which is a word formed from a verb (*to prepare*) that functions like an adjective.  So this is essentially a sentence in the [passive voice](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/passive-voice/), which is usually formed with "to be" + a past participle.